# Display loop result in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just started with ASP.NET and I'm having trouble with displaying a result from a loop. For example:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10) {

  Label1.Text = x+""; // This will show only result 9 ( last result ). 
    x++;
}
```

How do I show all results instead of only one?

Comment: `Label1.Text += x+"";`

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` and assign `Label1.Text` after loop.

Comment: @Pratik: Don't need `StringBuilder` here!!! [I Should Use StringBuilder Everywhere, Right? No its not!!](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Label1.Text = x+"";
```

Do:

```
Label1.Text = Label1.Text + x;
```

Answer (score 1):

> This will show only result 9 ( last result ).

Yes because you assign a new value to `Label1.Text` property in every iteration.

Try this instead;

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10)
{

  Label1.Text = Label1.Text + x;
  x++;
}
```

Or instead define a `string` value outside of `while` and add it this `int` values inside of your loop and assign your `.Text` value outside of your loop like;

```
int x = 0;
string s = "";
while (x < 10)
{

  s += x;
  x++;
}
Label1.Text = s;
```

Or use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) would be better if you use a lot of numbers;

```
int x = 0;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
while (x < 10)
{

  s.Append(x);
  x++;
}
Label1.Text = s.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you really need to use a `StringBuilder` for an iteration of 10?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty For this case, no. But if OP uses a lot of string concatenations, `StringBuilder` is of course better..

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;

while (x < 10) {

  Label1.Text += x+""; // This will show "123456789". 
    x++;
}
```

You need to add to the text in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a list of them :

```
Label1.Text += "," + x.ToString();
```

Or

```
Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "," + x.ToString();
```

Either way will produce the result :

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

You should accumulate the values of each element, something like this:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10) {
  Label1.Text = Label1.Text + x;
  x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;

while (x < 10) {

  Label1.Text += x.ToString();  
    x++;
}
```

Comment: You might improve this by adding a short comment to highlight the specific change.. for example, start off with "Use += to append:".

Answer (score 0):

You could use string builder

try this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int x = 0;

        while (x < 10) {
          sb.Append(x);
          sb.Append(" ");
            x++;
        }
 Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code as below, you gotta assign a new id to Label1.Text in every iteration.

```
int x = 0;
    while (x < 10)
    {
        label1.Text += x.ToString();
        x++;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Label1.Text = x+"";
```

with

```
  Label1.Text = Label1.Text + x.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`+=` append string to variable instead of replacing so,

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10) {
  Label1.Text += x+" "; //append space to separate  
    x++;
}
```